# Travis CI with Django 1.7.1 has operational error

Tags: django, travis-ci

I ask you about CI(Continuous Integration).

For using this service, I choose travis CI.

and problem is that in local test, there is no problem. but on travis I have error about operational error in db.

The reason in local is that there is no add to my app in installed app section.

I fixed it, but travis could not find my app, so it shows operational errors again and again.
I use Django 1.7.1 versions.

Is there anyone suggests me solutions??

I posted travis build log

```
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 88, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 147, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 109, in setup_databases
    return setup_databases(self.verbosity, self.interactive, **kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 299, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 385, in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 421, in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 128, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 52, in serialize
    for obj in queryset:
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 417, in get_objects
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 700, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 485, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: users_user
The command "python manage.py test" exited with 1.
```

and here is my travis.yml

```
language: python
python:
- '2.7'
install:
- pip install -r requirements.txt
script:
- python manage.py migrate
- python manage.py test
```

Comment: Can you post your entire .travis.yml?

Comment: @garnetb Here is it
language: python
python:
- '2.7'
install:
- pip install -r requirements.txt
script:
- python manage.py migrate
- python manage.py test

Comment: `python manage.py createsuperuser`? `syncdb` is deprecated as you said, but `migrate` does not prompt to create a superuser anymore.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate -> Unlike ...

Comment: @Bjorn after Django 1.7.1, syncdb command is deprecated.

Comment: and I think migrate command does not affect test command

Comment: How are you doing your tests? do you use factory boy or something?

Comment: @Mihai Zamfir I did not use factory boy just write test case

Comment: Why do you believe it is related with travis? can you run your tests on their own? if you can't, then it is not about Travis

Comment: I solved it, and it because local test is perfectly work. and travis is not.

Comment: The reason is that when travis test. I need to specify migrating each apps, for example, If my project contains app1, and app2, then, I have to typed as before_command in travis make migration for app1, app2 each. When I did that, travis is work. Is there any reason for that?